# How can i access my custom widget in view file in yii2

Tags: php, class, yii, yii2, widget

This is my custom widget (vendor\sliderWidget.php):

```
    <?php
namespace Mostafa;
use yii;

  class sliderWidget extends \yii\base\Widget {
    public function init() {
      parent::init();
 ...
```

But when i try to use this widget in view file (frontend\views\site\index.php ):

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\icons\Icon;
 ?>

<?= \Mostafa\sliderWidget::widget();?>
 ...
```

I got the

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class 'Mostafa\sliderWidget'
>   not found error

It seems the problem is autoloading. How should i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your folder with widget outside `vendor` folder and use PSR-4 standard.

If this is based on Basic Project Template you can put it in root folder like `/Mostafa`.
If this is based on Advanced Project Template you can put it in one of the application's folder like `/frontend/Mostafa`.

Name the widget class inside `Mostafa` folder properly like `SliderWidget.php` and name the class inside properly (`SliderWidget`).

In this file use proper namespace: for Basic it's `namespace app\Mostafa;`, for Advanced in the example it's `namespace frontend\Mostafa;`

Now you can use this widget properly. For Basic:

```
<?= \app\Mostafa\SliderWidget::widget() ?>
```

For Advanced in the example:

```
<?= \frontend\Mostafa\SliderWidget::widget() ?>
```

Comment: i did what you said but problem still exist :
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'frontend\Mostafa\SliderWidget' not found

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't do exactly what I said then.

Comment: me to!
 this is my widget file in frontend\mostafa\SliderWidget.php :

          namespace frontend\mostafa;
          class SliderWidget extends \yii\base\Widget {...
 
and when using it this way :

         <?= \frontend\mostafa\SliderWidget::widget();?>
i got same error

Comment: Full exception info with details. Switch your YII_DEBUG to true if it's false.

Comment: PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'frontend\mostafa\SliderWidget' not found

    1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\fajr-site\frontend\views\site\index.php at line 6
    123456789101112131415

    <?php
    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
     
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use kartik\icons\Icon;
    echo \frontend\mostafa\SliderWidget::widget();
     
     
     
    ?>
     
    <!--بخش های شرکت -->
    <!--
    <section class="group center">